# Python: calling process.terminate() doesn't kill it

Tags: python, windows, process, terminate

When I run the following code:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("...", shell=True)          
if p.poll() == None:
  p.kill()
```

The process is simply not killed. I'm on Windows.

I thought it was because of multithreading, I ran it in a single thread, still same thing.

Do you have any ideas why this could be happening?

Thanks

**Update**

I found the code that causes the problem:

```
while cur_time < self.time_limit:
            if p.poll() != None:
                too_much_time = False
                break
            time.sleep(0.1)
            cur_time += 0.1
```

I run this to make sure that the process doesn't take more than the time limit. Apparently that's why I can't kill the process.

Comment: @nmichaels, I tried both. Neither works. And they do the same thing on Windows, according to documentation.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "I can't kill the process": the loop doesn't contain `p.kill()` anywhere and you said that there is a single thread. Print `cur_time, self.time_limit` in the loop.

Comment: You don't need `shell=True` unless you are executing builtin in a shell commands such as `type`. `None` is a singleton; you could use `p.poll() is not None` in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use `shell=True`, all you end up killing is the shell (cmd.exe process) itself.

Process groups are a relatively new feature of Windows and I don't know of any software apart from Task Scheduler that actually uses them yet.

Comment: Thank you so much! Indeed, that's the reason. I didn't even think about the shell parameter. Why did I even use it?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the command you are running is setting the sigmask to ignore the kill signal. Can you try with another command? e.g make a script that sleeps in an infinite while and try to kill that

offtopic, I think shell arg doesn't mean anything on windows

Comment: I run the loop until the program stops. If it doesn't stop within n seconds, I kill it. The problem is that it doesn't want to get killed.

Comment: right; I tried to downvote my answer but it doesn't work :) It may be that the command you are running is setting the sigmask to ignore the kill signal. Can you try with another command? e.g make a script that sleeps in an infinite while and try to kill that